# File lookup and dentry cache

Tags: linux, filesystems

I understand detnries are about saving time by not accessing the disk to get a file's inode.

All the sources I read depict how an inode is found using the dentries.
None of them really describe how an inode is found if we have no dentries to it.

Let's say I want to access /home/dlv/src.c and the dentry cache is empty.
How would the OS create the new dentries?
Can you explain the rough mechanism? (from searching the disk and creating the dentry and setting its fields etc..).

Thank you,
Dolev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root directory entry of a file system is usually either in a well-known place, or has a well-known inode number, or the inode number for it is stored in the superblock or other file system metadata. From there, the blocks containing the directory entries for the root are scanned to find `home` - that dir entry will contain the inode number for `home`. The blocks referenced by that inode are then scanned to get the directory entries from `/home` and search for `dlv`. Repeat until you get to the last directory entry in the path, and scan that directory's inode for directory entries matching the file in question.

Thinking about that process for an extremely deeply nested file on a disk that takes 10ms per access should give you a good idea of the motivation for the directory entry cache... Finding a single deeply-nested file on disk can easily take hundreds of disk accesses.